# Como fazer com que tenha redirecionamento

Tags: c#, winforms, cmd

Fiz um aplicativo em C#, além de executar as funções básicas, quero que seja possível executar com scripts em lotes, mas o problema é que eu executo `Console.WriteLine` e ele não escreve nada na janela do CMD.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Programs
{
    static class Program
    {
        static Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, "TS4");
        /// 
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// 
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            if (mutex.WaitOne(TimeSpan.Zero, true))
            {
                if (args.Length > 0)
                {
                    Application.Run(new Form_Install());
                }
                else
                {
                    Trace.WriteLine("Missing Var packed_filename");
                    Trace.WriteLine("Missing Var packed_game");
                    Trace.WriteLine("Missing Var packed_type");
                    MessageBox.Show("Parâmetros não encontrados.");
                }

                mutex.ReleaseMutex();
                Trace.WriteLine("Mutex foi lançado!");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Erro ao processar solicitação! O aplicativo já está em execução, termine a outra instalação e tente novamente!" , "O Thread atual já está em uso!" , MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Também ouvi dizer do `Trace.WriteLine`, mas também não funcionou!

Comment: Ele não vai escrever no CMD. Isso é uma aplicação WinForms

Comment: Ah ta pensei q mesmo sendo de GUI ele gerasse output! Mas assim tem como esconder a janela do console?

Comment: Olha mesmo eu tendo mudado para Console Application ele não escreve nada no cmd

Comment: Ele até gera output, mas não é no CMD. Trocar pra Console App provavelmente não vai adiantar. Acho que o ideal é criar um Console App.

Comment: Você está usando Console.Write depois que mudou para console? @Nathan1302

Comment: Sim funcionou troquei o `Trace` para `Console` e funcionou. Mas como eu faço para esconder a janela do CMD do meu aplicativo?

Comment: Vc quer rodar um comando no cmd e manter a janela da sua aplicação console oculta isso? Se for isso eu montei um exemplo.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi, você pode utilizar a classe [Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.diagnostics.process%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) para criar um processo e a [ProcessStartInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) que ira especificar e definir as propriedades quando seu processo for inicializado, no caso o valores serão para o `cmd.exe`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RunCMDCommand
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startinfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();

            startinfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden; //Olcuta a janela da aplicação.
            startinfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            startinfo.Arguments = "/C explorer "; // O "/C" transporta o comando de saida especificado por uma string e conclui.

            process.StartInfo = startinfo;
            process.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

O programa executara o comando `explorer` como exemplo, que vem antes do `/C`, assim chamando o Windows Explorer, e a janela ficara oculta, você pode substituir por outros comandos.

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands).

Comment: Eu quero saber se ele redirecione por exemplo o cmd, mas o cmd já ta aberto sem precisar iniciar um novo processo

Comment: Como assim redirecionar cmd? Vc que obter a saída do comandos que são executados no cmd?

Comment: ex: tem um app ele já foi aberto, quero q meu programa use o RedirectStandardOutput nesse programa. é possivel?